# How to restrict specific words or numeric sequence in editText?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputedittext

in android is it possible to restrict edittext in order to reject and show an alert if some words are entered?
For example I need to exclude from the edittext input the following words and numerc sequences:
"123456", "0000", "administrator", "black" etc.
Someone can help me please?

I used the following code to check and show alert when edittext is blank

```
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        editTextName.setError("Please enter name");
        editTextName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
```

but I don't know how to check if was entered restricted words.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any research?

Comment: yes but without success.. I used the TextUtils in order to check if the edittext is empty but I don't know how to check if the user enterd restricted words or numeric sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a TextWatcher to your EditText `addTextChangedListener` and on

```
beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
```

check if the input is the one you trying to reject.

Comment: Thank you Estevex. Could you please explain how to use TextWatcher for this specific case? I'm trying to implement TextWatcher but somthing is wrong in my code..Thank you for patience.. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this but something is wrong

```
private class TextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {
    //before text changed
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

        if (editTextName.getText().toString() == "123456") ;
            editTextName.setError("Please enter correct words");
            editTextName.requestFocus();
            return;
    }
    //on text changed
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
    }
    //after text changed
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed){

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `editTextName.getText().toString() == "123456"` use something like `s.equals("123456")`

Comment: Thank you very much Estevex! I've solved with this:
`if (s.toString().matches("0|00|000|123|111|123|123456|1234|12345|9874"))`